# Can't save default fields in option page in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I've created custom option page based on this tutorial: https://www.wpexplorer.com/wordpress-theme-options/#admin-panel-class. I added to my fields 'default' option, like this:

```
'bhld_reusable_blocks_enabled' => array(
    'label'       => esc_html__( 'Show Reusable Blocks', 'behold-things' ),
    'type'        => 'checkbox',
    'description' => 'Enables Reusable Blocks menu in Admin area.',
    'default'     => true,
    'tab'         => 'tab-1',
),
```

and after saving settings, this default checkbox is unchecked. How to resolve that?

**edit**

whole code here: helper https://onlinephp.io/c/f1cc2 (it's long, that's why I don't post it here) and the option-page https://onlinephp.io/c/4143a

Comment: Post your all code

Comment: @Vel Here's full code https://onlinephp.io/c/f1cc2

Comment: It is resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this function

```
public function sanitize_fields( $value ) {
    $value = (array) $value;
    $new_value = [];
    foreach ( $this->settings as $key => $args ) {
        $field_type = $args['type'];
        $new_option_value = $value[$key] ?? '';
        if ( $new_option_value ) {
            $sanitize_callback = $args['sanitize_callback'] ?? $this->get_sanitize_callback_by_type( $field_type );
            $new_value[$key] = call_user_func( $sanitize_callback, $new_option_value, $args );
        } elseif ( 'checkbox' === $field_type ) {
           $new_value[$key] = call_user_func( $sanitize_callback, $new_option_value, $args );
        }
    }
    return $new_value;
}
```

I have changed this line  `$new_value[$key] = 0;` to `$new_value[$key] = call_user_func( $sanitize_callback, $new_option_value, $args );`

You are passing default value 0 for checkboxes.

**Updated answers**

**You need to use**

```
 update_option('additional_options', array('bhld_reusable_blocks_enabled' =>1));
```

Comment: Thanks for help, but still it doesn't change anything. After first plugin activation, option is default set to true (checked). After saving, these default options are gone.

Comment: where is the code for `After first plugin activation, option is default set to true (checked).`?

Comment: This default checked is created by `'default'     => true,` in array, in option-page, here https://onlinephp.io/c/4143a

Comment: when you activate the plugin set value for `additional_options` all default option in wp_options table

Comment: I've tried something like `this update_option( 'bhld_reusable_blocks_enabled', 'true' );` but that doesn't work either. Is each option (like `bhld_reusable_blocks_enabled`) should be visible in database separately?

Comment: You need to use `update_option('additional_options', array('bhld_reusable_blocks_enabled' =>1));`

Comment: Could you add an answer so I can mark it as solved? :)

Comment: Answers updated. Glad to help you:)